# Customizing ADD TO CART buttons based on user country and product Ids

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, country

In my WooCommerce store, I have some products which are only available in USA, I want to hide the "Add to Cart" button on a Single Product Page, when the geolocation finds any country other than USA.

If it is USA, show "add to cart', if it is not USA, hide "add to cart" button.

*(P.S. I used a plugin for that, but it is not working for some javascript conflict with other plugins.)*

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please provide some code, screenshots and/or link to your page

Comment: hello, I have edited my question above, can u plz take a look, I dont know what code to use in my functions.php in child theme.

Comment: Can you provide the single product page class(or something that indicates that it's USA) and the button "add to cart" id or class?

Comment: content-single-product.php is here https://codeshare.io/5eKr84
the CSS class is -  single_add_to_cart_button button alt

Comment: some class that connects to the country..?

Comment: I m not sure what u r saying  :( I know very little about woocommerce/wordpress hooks and filter

Comment: take a look, is this the class u mean -  https://ibb.co/hxihxF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151716/discussion-between-vagelis-and-tanvir).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When conditions match (specific product IDs and other countries), this code will replace the add to cart buttons in shop archives by a link to the product and in single product pages by a custom text.

> **You just need to set in:**
>
> - 1st function the needed country code … (for you 'US' and already done)
> - 2nd and 3rd functions your product IDs in the array

Here is the code:

```
// Conditional function country code detection
// @argument $code (string): country code restriction
// @return boolean
if( ! function_exists('is_from_country_code') ){

    // ==> HERE below set your country code (Replace 'US' by yours)
    function is_from_country_code( $code = 'US' ){
        $location = new WC_Geolocation;
        $user_ip = $location->get_ip_address();
        $user_country_code = $location->geolocate_ip( $user_ip, false, false )['country'];
        return $user_country_code == $code ? true : false;
    }
}

// Replace "Add to cart" single product button and quantity by a custom text
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'Custom_single_add_to_cart', 1 );
function Custom_single_add_to_cart(){
    global $product;

    // Set here your product IDS
    $product_ids = array( 56, 53, 50 );

    if( is_from_country_code() ||
         ( ! is_from_country_code() && ! in_array( $product->get_id(), $product_ids) ) )
        return; // Continue for foreign countries and the specific products IDs

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', function(){
        echo '<p class="custom-text">'.__('Not available for your country', 'woocommerce').'</p>';
    }, 30);
}

// Shop and archives pages: we replace the button add to cart by a link to the product
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'custom_text_replace_button', 10, 2 );
function custom_text_replace_button( $button, $product  ) {

    // Set here your product IDS
    $product_ids = array( 56, 53, 50 );

    if( is_from_country_code() ||
         ( ! is_from_country_code() && ! in_array( $product->get_id(), $product_ids) ) )
        return $button; // Continue for foreign countries and the specific products IDs

    $button_text = __("View product", "woocommerce");
    return '<a class="button" href="'.$product->get_permalink().'">'.$button_text.'</a>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on woocommerce version 3+ and works

Comment: Thank u very much, should I add them in my child theme's function.php ?

Comment: Hello, Its working for ALL Countries now, USA or Non-USA , Add to cart not shown even for USA,  can u check again plz.

Comment: @Tanvir … **Ok tested, solved and updated (3) … This time is good forever** … try it :)

Comment: IT JUST WORKED LIKE A CHARM BRO, THANK U SOOOOOO MUCH, Gracias ... God bless u